# Keycloak port 39008 and port scan

Tags: jboss, redhat, keycloak

I did a port scan using `nmap` on my machine running [Keycloak](http://www.keycloak.org/) and was surprised to find that port 39008 was open. According to `nmap`:

```
39008/tcp open  unknown
```

Using the following two commands I found that it is keycloak:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep 39008
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:39008           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17270/java   

ps -Af | grep 17270
me     17270 17223  0 Dec22 ?        00:13:05 java ...-Djboss.home.dir=/.../keycloak-2.4.0.Final
```

I cannot find any reference to this port in the config or the docs.

**What is this port used for?**